Task inside template can not read config file saved in the same repo
I prepared a template to re use it across all of my pipelines. It looks like this:
stages:
- stage: Defender
  displayName: Defender
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest
  jobs:
  - job: Scan
    displayName: Scan
    steps:
    - task: MicrosoftSecurityDevOps@1
      displayName: Microsoft Security DevOps
      inputs:
        config: ../configs/config.gdnconfig

Folder structure looks like this:
 - PROJ/ado-templates (root folder of template's repo)
   - templates
     - template.yml
   - configs
     - config.gdconfig

Then, in pipeline i use this template as present:
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: PROJ/ado-templates

stages:
- template: templates/microsoft-security.yml@templates

But during scan i got an error:

##[error]ConfigurationPathNotFoundException: A configuration file could not be found for: ../configs/config.gdnconfig. This is often due to attempting to use a tool on a platform where it is not yet supported.
##[error]MSDO CLI exited with an error exit code: 1

When i run ls -al $(Build.SourcesDirectory) script in this pipeline through template, i do not see that template files there. Only files from the repo where template is used
The question is, how to read config file that is saved in the same repo as template used in this pipeline?

You are only reference the yaml but not checkout the repo where config.gdnconfig exists.
Add checkout step in template.yaml:
stages:
- stage: Defender
  displayName: Defender
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest
  jobs:
  - job: Scan
    displayName: Scan
    steps:
     - checkout: templates
     - script: |
        cat configs/config.gdnconfig            # check the content
    - task: MicrosoftSecurityDevOps@1
      displayName: Microsoft Security DevOps
      inputs:
        config: configs/config.gdnconfig           # remove .. at the begining

In addition, make sure the config file name is correct.


It works! Thanks! but what in this case templates means? the @templates mark from mian repo where i declared pipeline? Can i parametrized that? how? Can we use keyword self or something like that in template?

The templates comes from your main pipeline, since you defined repository: templates, it's the repository name you defined. Actually you can edit main yaml -> click vertical 3 dots on top right -> Download full yaml, it will show the expanded yaml for you to check. The name is based on what you defined.

But what can i do in case someone will assign different name than templates?

@michasaucer careful - this works but it means that ALL pipelines that use the templates must use the same repository resource name: - repository: templates.

@michasaucer, you can define parameter in template for checkout, like checkout: ${{ parameters.reponame }}. and transfer the parameter from main.yaml.

Anyway, with your example now i have different issue. Instead of checking out main repo, template repo is checked out so i dont have source code to scan

Add checkout: self also in template.yaml, with two checkout steps to get all code. But pay attention to the repo structure, as multiple checkout will store the repo in reponamed folder. You can raise a new ticket and share the link so that we can check if you still have problem on the new issue.

Instead of using relative paths in the pipeline try using an absolute path, preceded by a predefined variable, such as:
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/path/to/my/config.file

Or, as an alternative:
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/path/to/my/config.file

Both $(Build.SourcesDirectory) and $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) point to the local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded.
Checking out shared templates
As mentioned in wade zhou - MSFT's answer:

You are only reference the yaml but not checkout the repo where config.gdnconfig exists

You can add a checkout step in your shared template but I suggest using a parameter containing the name of the repository to checkout, as follows:
parameters:
  - name: checkoutRepository
    type: string
    default: templates

stages:
  - stage: Defender
    displayName: Defender
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
    jobs:
    - job: Scan
      displayName: Scan
      steps:
      - checkout: ${{ parameters.checkoutRepository }}
      - task: MicrosoftSecurityDevOps@1
        displayName: Microsoft Security DevOps
        inputs:
          config: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/configs/config.gdnconfig

You can then using the template using the default value for parameter checkoutRepository:
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: PROJ/ado-templates

stages:
  - template: templates/microsoft-security.yml@templates

Or, as alternative, pass the name of the repository to checkout (in case for example the name templates is already set in another repository resource):
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: PROJ/my-other-templates
    - repository: adotemplates
      type: git
      name: PROJ/ado-templates

stages:
  - template: templates/microsoft-security.yml@adotemplates
    parameters:
      checkoutRepository: adotemplates


Thanks for your answer but the problem, is, when i do ls -al $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) command in separate task, i do not see template repo there so i dont know, how to reach that config file inside the pipeline

When you run the pipeline is there one or more checkout tasks?

Only one checkout for the repo where pipeline is configured. I do not see checkout for templates but indeed, they are used (because i am getting this error and the stage declared in template runs)

@michasaucer try the following: config: ../configs/config.gdnconfig@templates.

Tried that but i gave it one more try, still the same error: A configuration file could not be found for: ../configs/config.gdnconfig@templates.

Try explicitly checking out the 2 repos: - checkout: selfand - checkout: templates. Let me know in which folder are the templates checked out.

@michasaucer edited my answer.

The problem with that solution is that instead of running scan stage inside repo wher pipeline is declared you run it in templates repo which is not correct

Fixed last code sample. Copy-paste error, as usual :-)
